# Rails associations: something has many, but only one per other entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models. `User`, `Application` and `ApplicationVote`

The following are true:

1. An `ApplicationVote` belongs to both a `User` and an `Application`.
2. A `User` can cast a vote on an `Application`, thus creating an `ApplicationVote`
3. A user can vote on any number of applications, but can only have one vote per application.

If there would be a way to say `User has_many ApplicationVotes but only one per Application`... what would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

application level, into the `application_vote.rb` model file

```
validates_uniqueness_of :application_id, scope: :user_id
```

database level, in a migration file

```
add_index :application_votes, [:user_id, :application_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Thanks! And in the models? Just User has_many ApplicationVotes? That's where I'm most confused.

Comment: I'd say `has_many :application_votes`. At most one per application, but in general he/she can have many

Comment: Thanks again! Can you enlighten me regarding why the index is needed?

Comment: don't trust the application level :) the database level is the only one that can give you the guarantee you want

Comment: if you receive a lot of concurrent requests the application level can fail sometimes